# Python directory file issue

Tags: python, directory, urllib, glob

My problem is that when downloading an **File** with the python **urllib.request Module(s)** that the current File being downloaded is being put in the **same directory as the script**. I can't seem to find any solution that works, I tied to use the **glob module** but no succes here.

**No glob method**

```
# Importing required libraries
import urllib.request

# Adding information about user agent
opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

# setting filename and image URL
filename = 'sunshine_dog.jpg'
image_url = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/06/09/39/summer-4823612_960_720.jpg"

# calling urlretrieve function to get resource
urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, filename)
```

**Glob method**

```
# Importing required libraries
import urllib.request
import glob

# Adding information about user agent
opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

# setting filename and image URL
filename = 'sunshine_dog.jpg'
image_url = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/06/09/39/summer-4823612_960_720.jpg"

# calling urlretrieve function to get resource
urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, filename)
glob.glob("/home/users/*/*.png")
```

If i did not succeed in informating you please tell me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the file to a specific directory, use a full path in the second argument to `urlretrieve()` instead of a bare filename:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, '/full/path/to/some/image.jpg')
```